# calculating cost of items listed in a listbox in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I've got a project on VB.net. I want to create a simple app that adds the price of every item on my list box 
which are

item            quantity

car.              1000

boats.           3000

bikes.            700

hats.             49

and give me an answer in a textbox

I added 1 listbox, 1 button, and 1 text box
I populated the list box with the items above 
I want to sum the quantity of these items how can I do that ?
please I m new to VB.net

Comment: we cant possibly help without knowing much more like what is in the ListBox and where to get things like the price.  Please add the code you have (or write some) to show what you are attempting.

Answer (score 0):

Here....try this....new project, one form, one
command button and two listboxes:
Code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim i,j As long
  List2.Clear
  For i = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
    For j = 0 To List2.ListCount - 1

If List1.List(i) = List2.List(j) Then
     List2.ItemData(j) =List1.ItemData(j) + 1
        Exit For
      End If
    Next j
    If j = List2.ListCount Then
      List2.AddItem List1.List(i)
      List2.ItemData(List2.NewIndex) = 1
    End If
  Next i
  For j = 0 To List2.ListCount - 1
    List2.List(j) = List2.List(j) & " " &
List2.ItemData(j)
  Next j
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

List1.AddItem ("CHAIR")
List1.AddItem ("CHAIR")
List1.AddItem ("PHONE")
List1.AddItem ("CHAIR")
List1.AddItem ("CARDS")
List1.AddItem ("PHONE")
End Sub
```

Comment: This may be useful to you: [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: this is not tagged VB6 - there is no `ItemData` or `.Additem` in .NET and the Click event signature is also wrong for .NET